# toPromise() works, but pipe(share()) does not work in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `ASP.Net Core WebApi` with `Angular 6` as front end.

Below is the `WebApi` method I am calling from `Angular`

```
[HttpPut("GetUsersPagewise/{userId}/{accountId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersPagewise(string userId, Guid ownerAccountId, [FromHeader] string authorization)
{
    ApiResponse<UserGridResult> response = new ApiResponse<UserGridResult>(null);
    response.StatusCode = _userValidationLogic.AreValidIds(new Guid(userId));
    try
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == ApiStatusCode.Ok)
        {
            response.ResponseObject  = await _assetLogic.GetUsersPagewise(userId, ownerAccountId, authorization);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        response.StatusCode = ApiStatusCode.InternalError;
    }

    return ResponseResult(response);
}
```

Below is the `Angular` code in the `Service` file

```
public GetUsersPagewise(userId: string, ownerAccountId: string): Observable<User[]> {
    this.dataJson = this.httpClient.put<any>(this.uriBase + 'User/GetUsersPagewise/' + userId + '/' + ownerAccountId, { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' } }).toPromise();
    return this.dataJson.data;
}
```

When I change the above code from `toPromise()` to `pipe(share())`, the cursor is not hitting the `WebApi` method listed above.

What I have to make to hit the backend `GetUsersPagewise` method?

**EDIT**

Actually, I am getting the data from `WebApi` with pipe(share()) as an extention method for GetUsersPagewise like below

```
public GetUsersPagewise(userId: string, ownerAccountId: string): Observable<User[]> {
    this.dataJson = this.httpClient.put<any>(this.uriBase + 'User/GetUsersPagewise/' + userId + '/' + ownerAccountId, { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }}).pipe(share());
    return this.dataJson.data;
}
```

This is in `KendoGridService` file. Next, I call the Query in the same file like below...

```
public GetUsersPagewiseQuery(userId: string, ownerAccountId: string): Observable<User[]> {
    const users :any = this.GetUsersPagewise(userId, ownerAccountId);
    super.next(users);
    return users;
}
```

Next I call `GetUsersPagewise` in `ApiService` as below...

```
public GetUsersPagewise(userId: string, ownerAccountId: string): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.kendoGridService.GetUserAssetsPagewiseQuery(userId, ownerAccountId);
}
```

Finally in `UsersService` I call `subscribe` method as below...

```
public GetUsersPagewise(userId: string, ownerAccountId: string): Observable<User[]> {
    this.spinner.show();
    const obs$ = this.apiService.GetUsersPagewise(userId, ownerAccountId);
    obs$.subscribe((usersToValidate: User[]) => {
      this.usersToValidate = usersToValidate;
      this.users = usersToValidate;
      this.Updated.emit(this.users);
      this.spinner.hide();
    },
      (errror: any) => {
        this.Updated.emit(this.users);
        this.spinner.hide();
      });
    return obs$;
}
```

At the end I get error as below...

[image: Subscribe]

How can I assign the end value to `User[]` variable. I am still not able to understand `Observable<User[]>`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're calling `.subscribe()` on your observable after you use your pipe/operators. A common gotcha with the HttpClient methods (or [cold observables](https://benlesh.medium.com/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) in general) is that the code won't execute unless subscribed to, e.g.

```
getUsers() {
  this.serviceName
    .GetUsersPagewise( // ...arguments )
    .subscribe(
      (users: User[]) => { // do something }
    )
}
```

If you instead did this, your PUT would not be called

```
getUsers() {
  this.serviceName.GetUsersPagewise( // ...arguments )
}
```

Comment: Edit the Question with detailed explanation on how I am calling the `subscribe()` and `pipe(share())` for `GetUsersPagewise` method. Hope you would provide me some clarity on where to use `pipe(share(())` and where to use `subscribe()` to get the end result. Thank you in advance.